# Vert.x 3 documentation for Scala

Tags: scala, vert.x

[Here](http://vertx.io/vertx2/core_manual_scala.html) is the documentation about using Vert.x 2 with Scala.

Is there documentation about using Scala with vert.x 3? Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Scala for Vert.x 3 yet. You should follow the GitHub repository [vertx-lang-scala](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-scala).

At work we are using the Vert.x 3 Java API with Scala. It works as it should. But "native" Scala support which makes use of Scala language features would be great.

Drop some lines in favor on the Vert.x mailing list. So perhaps it gets a higher priority.

**Edit:** vertx-lang-scala is now officially part of [Vert.x 3.4.0](http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-3-4-0-is-released/)!